# subclassing UINavigationController and adding a sliding menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My goal: To have a sliding menu that will push the current view of my app when it opens.

I've subclassed my `UINavigationController` in order to create custom "back" buttons and the sliding from the right menu. To do so, inside my subclassed `UINavigationController` i'm changing the x origin of the current `UIViewController` (`self.view.fram`) to a value that will move it to the left `x = -100;` and by doing so i'm exposing the right menu.

After completing the above I've found out that by moving `self.view` I'm also moving the touchable area so the button on the right menu won't be accesible \ clickable.

I've read a lot about `pointInside` and `hitTest` that can help me achieve what i want but still couldn't implement it in a way that will fit my needs.

I'm aware that there are a 1000 open source projects on github that do exactly what I want but 'd like to write it my self and understand it better.

Thanks.

**NavControllerSubCls.h:**

```
@interface NavControllerSubCls : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *testView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *rightMenuBtn;

@end
```

**NavControllerSubCls.m:**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIView *navBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 41)];
    navBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIImageView *bkrNavBar = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 39)];
    [navBar addSubview:bkrNavBar];    


    _rightMenuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [_rightMenuBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 20, 52, 19)];
    [_rightMenuBtn setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_rightMenuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showRightMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [navBar addSubview:_rightMenuBtn];    

    _testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 20, 120, 100)];
    _testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIButton *testBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    testBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 100);
    [testBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_testView addSubview:testBtn];
    [self.view addSubview:_testView];

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];    
    [self.view insertSubview:_testView aboveSubview:self.view];


}

-(void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"I'm Working!");
}


- (void)showRightMenu
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = -100;
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like the Facebook app? I think a better design would be to have a parent view controller that manages the sliding and two child view controllers, one for the menu and one for the content.

### EDIT

The `SlidingViewController` has two child view controllers: a `ContentViewController` that takes up all the space and a `MenuViewController` underneath the `ContentViewController`.

The `SlidingViewController` only manages the sliding interaction, whether that's coming from a pan gesture or from a method call. When it's time to show the menu, the `SlidingViewController` will shift the `ContentViewController` so that the `MenuViewController` is visible (by changing the `transform` or `frame` property).

The `ContentViewController` and `MenuViewController` are just containers for the real view controllers. You use these containers so that you can do whatever you want to them (say if you want to do some really funky animation) without affecting the real view controllers.

So the view controller hierarchy would look like this:

```
                SlidingViewController
                   /             \
        MenuViewController    ContentViewController
                |                      |
UITableViewController, etc.   UINavigationController, etc.
```

Comment: This is how I implemented the same type of thing for my app.  I also used a custom navigation bar so that I could set it's location, allowing me to give the appearance of the nav-bar sliding as if the navigation controller were moving.

Comment: @fumoboy007 So when you want to show the sliding menu you kinda half push that menu viewController on top of your current ViewController?  Some sample code would be great.

Comment: Again, very similar to how I set things up myself, though I didn't have a UINavigationController within my ContentViewController.  I suppose it would make it unnecessary to make your own nav bar (and be able to push views to the contentView without having to change the Menu if you want the menu to be used throughout several views of the app).  My menu only existed on one view and once you went deeper it was gone so the custom nav bar suited me well.  Either way, a good solution.

Comment: follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474652/pushing-a-view-controller-using-another-uinavigationcontroller :)