# Creating a delegate to change views from a menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, delegates

I want to be able to push view controllers to my main subclassed navigation controller from my custom menu and I want to do it using a delegate. Before I'm trying to change view controllers I went for something easier , to change the current view controller title.
This is the code I wrote so far but taping on the TableView cell will not trigger the delegate. (or so it seems)

Please advise

```
                -> RootViewController
                 /                   \
            Container                Container       
                |                         |
     SlideMenuViewController        SubClassed UINavigationController
                |                          |    |    |    |
     UITableViewController                VC1  VC2  VC3  VC4
```

**SlideMenuViewController.h:**

```
@protocol SlidingMenuDelegate <NSObject>

@end

@interface SlideMenuViewController : UIViewController
{
        id <SlidingMenuDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
```

**SlideMenuViewController.m:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //do something to send controller

    ((UIRTLNavigationController *)(self.delegate)).titleForView.text = @"test";
}
```

**MyNavigationController.h:**

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleForView;
```

**MyNavigationController.m:**

```
- (void)showRightMenu
{
...
...
//Some animation to slide the menu out

    //Delegate stuff
    //Get the storyboard's instance.
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    SlideMenuViewController *slideMenuVC;

    //Get the viewcontrollers instance from the storyboard's instance
    slideMenuVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"slideMenuSID"];
    slideMenuVC.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Where is the delegate being set? Why does the protocol not have any method definitions? Delegate properties shouldn't usually be `strong`. Debug or add some logging code to see that happens when the table cell is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SlidingMenuDelegate` protocol needs some (optional) methods such as `slidingMenu:didSelectOption:`. Also, I would define an enum or something that specifies all of the options that the menu provides.

Then in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you would do

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(slidingMenu:didSelectOption:)]) {
    SlidingMenuOption option;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        option = SlidingMenuFooOption;
        break;

    case 1:
        option = SlidingMenuBarOption;
        break;

    // ...
    }

    [self.delegate slidingMenu:self didSelectOption:option];
}
```

Finally, your delegate would do something in response to this `slidingMenu:didSelectOption:` message (e.g. set the title of the navigation controller).